# perl script to parse log files from different test locations.which takes dynamic path of testcases

Tags: perl

I want a perl script that will go in to every test folder and parse the log file in it.

Eg:

```
results/testcases/ **?** /test.log
```

The above path must be dynamically changing with different test folder names in the place of `**?**` mark.

I am using this `results/testcases/@array/test.log`

`@array` has test names

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be:

```
my $path = "results/testcases";
opendir(TEMPDIR,$path) or die "err1";

my @dir = grep -d, readdir TEMPDIR; 

foreach(@dir)
{
    if( $_ !~ /\./ )
    {
    open( my $fileHandle , "results/testcases/".$_."/test.log" ) or die "err2";
    # parsing log file
    close $fileHandle or die "err2-2";
    }
}

close TEMPDIR or die "err1-2";
```

First, you need to read the folder "results/testcases" for current correct folder names. Second, you need to open the files one by one, stead of putting @array in the middle of the path. Third, you should read basic perl, otherwise you won't be able to parse in a proper manner. Fourth, you really should read through [HOW TO ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?), you should put in your code so that we could be more helpful and your questions shall help others, as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your test folders relative paths are stored in `@array`. You can do the following:

```
my @testlogs = grep { -e $_ } map { "results/testcases/".$_."/test.log" } @array;
```

The new array `@testlogs` now contains the list of paths to existing 'test.log' files.

Then, you can parse each file like this:

```
map { ... parsing call ... } @testlogs;
```